# Bad idea to keep htop running?

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring

I'm now monitoring multiple servers (3) and in the coming weeks that'll increase (towards 5 or 6). I've been keeping three terminal windows open running htop via SSH and I'm now wondering if there **are any downsides to having a connection constantly open to production servers?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What i usually do is running a screen session for every server i need to monitor/manage, so i can detach it, disconnect from SSH and when i need to reconnect i still have there...

btw i've been keeping terminals connected via ssh for most of the day (8/9 hrs.) for the last 5 years
and never had a problem related to it.

Answer (score 6):

Do you really need to use htop to monitor ?  An alternative would be to use something like [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/), which records the resource usage from each server and plots it on a centralized web page.  This way you get the resources usage trends over time as well as the current values.

Comment: No I really don't. And next week once I conguer Nagios (and fully learn to trust it) I won't need to. But for the next couple of weeks, htop is what I got.